# can't get clipboard data in foeground

Tags: flutter, dart, background-service, dart-async, flutter-background

I am trying to monitor the clipboard in the foeground by running a check on it every 500 milliseconds but for some reason it's not working...

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (timer) async {

    print("Called");

    ClipboardData? currentClip = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
    print("Called 2");



    if (currentClip?.text != lastClip) {
      print("Clipboard data changed: ${currentClip?.text}");
      flutterLocalPlugin.show(
          90,
          "clipSync",
          "Copied ${DateTime.now()}",
          NotificationDetails(android: AndroidNotificationDetails("clipSync", "clipSync is Running", ongoing: true, icon: "app_icon")));
      socket.emit('copy', currentClip?.text);
      lastClip = currentClip?.text;
    }

 

  });
```

For some weird reason `Called` prints but `Called 2` doesn't

I tried wrapping it in a try and catch block but I got no error

Comment: On what platform are you running the app? Also, you may want to try to rethink whether you really need to watch on the clipboard like that as it seems to ignore user's privacy. If you only want to check for a certain format of the data in the clipboard, you may try [`canProvide`](https://pub.dev/documentation/super_clipboard/latest/super_clipboard/ClipboardReader/canProvide.html) from the `super_clipboard` package.